# How to correct the formatting of a file using unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file which I want to convert into proper delimiting format. I am not finding presently what is the delimiter. Below is the file, which is having column names and one row of data. Can anyone please suggest how this can be converted into '|' delimited form ?

```
E_Date        P_F_No_1 P_F_No_2    
     P_F_No_3                                                                                                                                                                                        
     P_F_No_4
     F_Name                                                                                                                                                                                               
     F_C_Cde L_Dte             C_Dte  
     I_No                  CBL_F_Cde P_S_Sec_No
     P_S_F_No P_S_Sys_Name CD     
     P_F_Range Sh_Cl          Al_Mgmt_F A_Fee  
     Ad_Fee Amt_Dte         
     S_Number                                                       
     B_No               
 ---------------------- ---------------- --------------------
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ----------------
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ------------ ---------------------- -----------
     ------------------------ ------------ --------------------------
     ---------------------- -------------------------- -----------
     ----------------- -------------------- --------------- -----------
     ----------- ----------------------
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     ---------------------- 
 20140822                             58 I                   
     Investor Prime Money Market Fund - Class I                                                                                                                                                         
                 NULL
     Investor Prime Money Market Fund - Class I                                                                                                                                                         
     USD          20020109                      NULL
     US842811723                     NULL                       NULL
                       NULL SUN                               NULL
                  NULL I                               NULL        NULL
            NULL 20140822              
     8741525800001                                                       
     20140822
```

Comment: Looks like this file is created as spool from oracle ... I would suggest if possible to format it at the source end.... just add few sqlplus variables in session generating this file...eg. set colsep | ; set trimspool on; set linesize 1000; set pages 0; ...

Comment: I am not able to set the colsep in sql because I am directly capturing the output of a stored procedure. Which is the above mentioned file. How can I do the formatting now ?

Comment: You can try setting these parameters before you call the script which is producing this output ... I don't think it will be easy to format the output as your column data also has spaces, you can still give it a try if your output is on one line using fixed width of the column defined in the table structure...using awk but will not guarantee correct results.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to make these changes using awk? I am just executing the stored procedure using isql command. Not sure how can I adjust the spaces while executing the stored procedure.

Comment: Can you please show how you are executing the procedure in isql, the content of script and how you are calling the script.

Comment: I am using below command : 
-isql -SMTSD_NEW -Uadmin -DDEV 
password 
execute sp_test
go
and as an output of above commands I am getting the data which I have specified above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try giving 2 more options.. in your isql command -s"|" -w1000 and then execute procedure 
Also you can add more option as required... see below link on meaning of these options...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa214007(v=sql.80).aspx

-s will set the field delimiter

-w to set the width of the line.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved my problem. Using -s, I have got the proper file. Thanks !!